# How do cookies get store on a local machine?

Tags: http, cookies

Let's say I create a cookie with a certain name and other server also creates a cookie with same name as well. Obviously this cookies do not get overiden by each other but how does that work. Is there a specific naming convention that is used for this not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are stored by the browser per domain. Thus, as long as cookies are uniquely named per domain, different can Web sites can create cookies with the same name.

For the IETF standards track documentation, check here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265